# buffer overrun when loading from a previous saved file

Tags: c, load, save, ini

I made a text adventure with a load/save option.
In the folder I created the game it worked fine. And even if I do a release version of my game it all works how it should.

But I have to give this project to my professor.
On my PC the saving and loading works fine but on my laptop or a copy of my projectfolder, i get the errormessage "a buffer overrun has accured".
So what's my fault here?

My Code to load/save:

```
bool save()
{
    char sFileText[1024];
    char sFileName[80];
    char sFileDirectory[80];

     GetCurrentDirectory(512, sFileDirectory); 

    sprintf(sFileName, "%s\\save_game.ini", sFileDirectory);

    sprintf(sFileText, "[settings]\n\rsp_loop=%i\n\rroom_iSelect=%i\n\riSelect=%i\n\rraum=%i\n\rtor402=%i\n\rwegiSelect=%i\n\rwegweiser=%i\n\rlight=%i\n\ropen_door=%i\n\rmesser=%i\n\rmesserwurf=%i\n\rkamera=%i\n\rstein=%i\n\ralive=%i\n\rpfeil=%i\n\rluke=%i\n\rkuehlschrank=%i\n\rpulver_schmand=%i\n\rteddy=%i\n\rseil=%i\n\rgiftklinge=%i\n\r",
         sp_loop,
         room_iSelect,
         iSelect,
         raum,
         tor402,
         wegiSelect,
         wegweiser,
         light,
         open_door,
         messer,
         messerwurf,
         kamera,
         stein,
         alive,
         pfeil,
         luke,
         kuehlschrank,
         pulver_schmand,
         teddy,
         seil,
         giftklinge
        );


    int cur_char;
    FILE *out_file;

    out_file = fopen(sFileName, "w");
    if (!out_file == NULL) 
    {
        for (cur_char = 0; cur_char < strlen(sFileText); ++cur_char) 
        {
            fputc(sFileText[cur_char], out_file);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    fclose(out_file);
    return true;
}

bool open()
{
    char sFileText[1024];
    char sFileName[12];
    char sFileGameSettingsIni[80];

    sprintf(sFileName, "save_game.ini");



    GetCurrentDirectory(512, sFileGameSettingsIni); 

    sprintf(sFileGameSettingsIni, "%s\\%s", sFileGameSettingsIni, sFileName);

    sp_loop = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "sp_loop", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);

    raum = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "raum", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    tor402 = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "tor402",512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    wegiSelect = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "wegiSelect", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    wegweiser = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "wegweiser", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    light = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "light", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    open_door = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "open_door",512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    messer = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "messer", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    messerwurf = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "messerwurf", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    kamera = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "kamera", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    stein = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "stein", 512,sFileGameSettingsIni);
    alive = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "alive", 512,sFileGameSettingsIni);
    pfeil = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "pfeil", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    luke = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "luke", 512,  sFileGameSettingsIni);
    kuehlschrank = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "kuehlschrank", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    pulver_schmand = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "pulver_schmand", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    teddy = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "teddy", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    seil = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "seil", 512, sFileGameSettingsIni);
    giftklinge = GetPrivateProfileInt("settings", "giftklinge",512, sFileGameSettingsIni);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: should be tagged C instead of c++ I reckon. Probably more code needed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `sFileName` as `sFileName[12]` and then attempt to write 14 bytes to it (13 and a NULL). It also looks like the buffer you are passing to `GetCurrentDirectory()` isn't big enough. You are stating the buffer is 512 bytes in length, when you only define it as 80 characters wide.

The return value of `GetCurrentDirectory()` will inform you of how large the buffer needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause is incorrect use of [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
char sFileDirectory[80];

GetCurrentDirectory(512, sFileDirectory);
```

This says that `sFileDirectory` can hold a maximum of 512 characters: it can hold a maximum of 80 only (including NULL terminator) so this could easily write beyond the end of `sFileDirectory`.

Change to:

```
GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(sFileDirectory) - 1, sFileDirectory); /* Check the return value. */
```

It may work on your PC due to shorter current directory, where on a different PC it could be stored in a directory with a path greater than 79 characters.

Another problem is:

```
char sFileName[12];

sprintf(sFileName, "save_game.ini");
```

"save_game.ini" is 13 characters long.
Change to:

```
char sFileName[14];

sprintf(sFileName, "save_game.ini");
```

or:

```
const char* sFileName = "save_game.ini";
```

Also consider using [_snprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) instead of `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

sFileDirectory it's pretty small compared to the buffer size for GetCurrentDirectory. Try to enlanrge to fit the same size. It's probably different on release machine.

Comment: i found a pretty simple solution...
instead of writing sFileName[12];
i wrote
sFileName[] = "save_game.ini";
Now this works fine!
Thx a lot to all!